# Сокрытие использования PHP

Tags: php

В статье ["PHP: фрактал плохого дизайна"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142140/) на хабре, открыл [ссылку](http://phpsadness.com/sad/11) и на открывшейся странице открыл еще одну ссылку [PHP Credits](http://xdebug.com/index.php?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000).

Далее попробовал аналогичное (`?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000`) на знакомых сайтах, отобразилось, но не на всех, что значит, есть решение.

Немного погуглив, ответ нашелся, в настройках `php.ini` установить `expose_php = Off`.

Топик не является вопросом, а может информация кому пригодится.

[Еще по теме](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/disable-php-expose-disable-php-credits-page-showing-up-with-including-some-phpphpb8b5f2a0-3c92-11d3-a3a9-4c7b08c10000-variable-to-a-php-powered-webserver/).

Comment: "Сокрытие использования PHP"... Такое ощущение что PHP вне закона :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope: Ну, не всё так однозначно. Указав фреймворк, которым вы пользуетесь, вы облегчаете жизнь хакеру, пытающемуся взломать ваш сайт. Он может подыскать 0day-exploit для вашего фреймворка, а не пробовать всё подряд, рискуя быть замеченным админами ресурса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти "яйца" скажут лишь о том что приложение написано на пхп. Ну и какие модули. Это настолько бесполезная хрень, что если вы проверите логи какого-нибудь старого сайта, то не увидите подобных запросов на сервер.